# Converting substrings of music from BASIC to C++

Tags: c++, playback, basic, indirection

In many versions of Basic, Music can be played with the statement PLAY. It accepts as its arguments, notes, octaves, etc, but also substrings.
as an example, `A$="BCD": B$="FDE": PLAY "XA$;O3XB$;"` is equivalent to `PLAY "BCDO3FDE"`

I want to do the same in C++. I know that is is difficult, as BASIC is interpreted and C++ compiled, but is there a way ?

To be more precise, I already have a function `PlayString(AnsiString ss)`, that is able to play a string made of notes (e.g. "BCD"), octaves (prefix O plus a digit, e.g."O2"), note length (prefix L plus a number, e.g."L4"), so a string to play could be "BCDO3FDE" (the same as above).

I want to add to it the necessary code to play a substring, say with prefix X, so that code as in the line below would work :

```
AnsiString aa="BCD", bb="FDE";PlayString("Xaa;O3Xbb;");
```

and be equivalent to

```
PlayString("BCDO3FDE");
```

Idea(s), anyone ?

Answer (score 0):

As written, this cannot work. The reason is exactly what you suspected: C++ is compiled. Variable names do not exist at run time. But `PlayString` interprets its argument only at run time. You need

```
PlayString(aa+"O3"+bb);
```